# Simple where condition for JPA CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

So this is my first attempt to use JPA and a `CriteriaQuery`.

I have the following (simplified) entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hours")
@XmlRootElement
public class Hours implements Serializable
{
    @EmbeddedId
    protected HoursPK hoursPK;

    @Column(name = "total_hours")
    private Integer totalHours;

    @JoinColumn(name = "trainer_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Trainer trainer;

    public Hours()
    {
    }

    ... getter and setter for the attributes
}

@Embeddable
public class HoursPK implements Serializable
{
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "date_held", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateHeld;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "trainer_id", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String trainerId;

    @Column(name = "total_hours")
    private Integer totalHours;


    public HoursPK()
    {
    }

    ... getter and setter ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "trainer")
public class Trainer implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "firstname", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String firstname;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "lastname", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String lastname;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "trainer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Hours> hoursList;

    ... more attributes, getters and setters

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Hours> getHoursList() {
       return hoursList;
    }

    public void setHoursList(List<Hours> hoursList) {
      this.hoursList = hoursList;
    }
}
```

Essentially a `Trainer` holds trainings and the hours spent in the trainings are stored in the `Hours` entity. The PK for the `hours` table is (`trainer_id, date_held)` as each trainer only holds one training per day.

I am trying to create a `CriteriaQuery` to fetch all hours of a trainer for a specific month. This is my attempt:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = ...
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Hours> c = builder.createQuery(Hours.class);

Root<Hours> root = c.from(Hours.class);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2014, 0, 1);
Expression<Date> from = builder.literal(cal.getTime());

cal.set(2014, 1, 1);
Expression<Date> to = builder.literal(cal.getTime());

Predicate who = builder.equal(root.get(Hours_.trainer), "foobar"); // it fails here

Predicate gt = builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(Hours_.hoursPK).get(HoursPK_.dateHeld), from);
Predicate lt = builder.lessThan(root.get(Hours_.hoursPK).get(HoursPK_.dateHeld), to);

c.where(gt,lt,who);
c.orderBy(builder.asc( root.get(Hours_.hoursPK).get(HoursPK_.dateHeld)  ));

TypedQuery<Hours> q = em.createQuery(c);

List<Hours> resultList = q.getResultList();
```

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.1 as the JPA provider and the above code fails with the exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [foobar] did not match expected type [persistence.Trainer (n/a)]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateBinding(BaseQueryImpl.java:885)

Apart from the fact that this seems awfully complicated for a query that even a SQL newbie could write in a few minutes, I have no clue, how I can supply the correct value for the `trainer_id` column in the `hours` table in the above query.

I also tried:

```
Predicate who = builder.equal(root.get("trainer_id"), "foobar");
```

But that fails with the exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [trainer_id] on this ManagedType [persistence.Hours]

It works, when I obtain an actual entity instance that maps to the `"foobar"` id:

```
CriteriaQuery<Trainer> cq = builder.createQuery(Trainer.class);
Root<Trainer> trainerRoot = cq.from(Trainer.class);
cq.where(builder.equal(trainerRoot.get(Trainer_.id), "foobar"));
TypedQuery<Trainer> trainerQuery = em.createQuery(cq);  
Trainer foobarTrainer = trainerQuery.getSingleResult();
....
Predicate who = builder.equal(root.get(Hours_.trainer), foobarTrainer);
```

But that seems a pretty stupid (and slow) way to do it.

I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious here, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First of all, JPA queries always use class and field names. Never column names. So trying to use `trainer_id` won't work.

```
builder.equal(root.get(Hours_.trainer), "foobar");
```

You're trying to compare the trainer field of the Hours entity with the String "foobar". trainer is of type Trainer. A Trainer can't be equal to a String. Its ID, it firstName, or its lastName, all of type String, can be compared to a String. SO you probably want

```
builder.equal(root.get(Hours_.trainer).get(Trainer_.id), "foobar");
```

That said, as you noticed, the Criteria API is extremely complex and leads to unreadable, hard to maintain code. It's useful when you have to dynamically compose a query from several optional criteria (hence the name), but for static queries, you should definitely go with JPQL, which is even easier and shorter than SQL:

```
select h from Hours h 
where h.trainer.id = :trainerId
and h.hoursPK.dateHeld >= :from
and h.hoursPK.dateHeld < :to
order by h.hoursPK.dateHeld
```

I would strongly advise against using composite keys, especially when one of its components is a functional data (dateHeld) that could have to change. Use numeric, single-column, autogenerated primary keys, and everything will be much simpler, and more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, the `root.get(Hours_.trainer).get(Trainer_.id)` did the trick. Regarding the composite PK: this is one of my biggest criticism of ORMs: they force you to use PKs that are the "real thing". Adding an autogenerated column to the hours table does improve the model from a relational point of view. It only adds the overhead of another index to the table without giving any benefit (in SQL). After I played around with this I agree: the benefits of the type safety that the API gives us does not warrant the complexity of it.

Comment: How does JPA force you to use a composite key? To the contrary: using a single-column key is much easier. Or did I misunderstand you? An autogenerated key greatly improves the model: it avoids having foreign keys with two columns in all the tables referencing the hours column, it makes joins faster, and it doesn't force you to modify the PK and all the FKs, when you realize that a dateHeld value must be changed.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I meant to write *that are **not** the "real thing"*. If the real PK *is* a composite key, I don't see any benefit in adding an additional column and index just to make the ORM's life easier. PKs don't change and in this case they really won't. And if Murphy comes along that it's much cleaner to delete the wrong information and add the correct one back in

Comment: Except if you have dozens of FKs pointing to it. Suppose the "natural" key for some other table "bar" is the couple "hours-foo". You'll end up with a PK with 3 columns. Now suppose the "natural" key for some other table "baz" is the couple "bar-bing", you'll end up with a PK with 4 columns. I've seen apps where they used "natural" keys, and had tables with 11 columns, 9 of which were part of the PK and contained data that had nothing to do with the table.

Comment: And if you need a link in your webapp that references a row from such a table, you need 2 or 3 parameters in the URL, with a date that needs to be parsed in one of them, instead of a simple integer. surrogate PKs are a better design, whether or not an ORM is used.

Comment: I was googling for such an answer for a few hours. Glad I've finally have found it. Thank you!